# Checking if values in a list appear in another list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I've got a list with 2 values in it. I want to compare those values against a 3 ranges (lotSize) - each range has a single value associated with it - so ultimately I want to be able to reference this final value when one of the 2 values falls within either of the 5 ranges.

The 2 values to compare:

```
countList = [150,250]
```

Currently I have a list for the range values e.g.

```
lotSize = [{'range': range(100,200), 'finalValue': 10},{'range': range(201,300), 'finalValue': 20},{'range': range(301,400), 'finalValue': 30},]
```

I have no idea how to go about seeing if the values in countList are in one of the ranges and if true then getting the "finalValue" - I imagine a for loop would be needed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
countList = [150,250,1000]

lotSize = [{'range': range(100,200), 'finalValue': 10},{'range': range(201,300), 'finalValue': 20},{'range': range(301,400), 'finalValue': 30},]

def get_fv(cl):
fv =[]
for c in cl:
    for ls in lotSize:
        r = ls['range']
        if c in r:
            fv.append(ls['finalValue'])
else:
      print(f"No range found for {c}")
return fv

print(get_fv(countList))
```

Output:

```
No range found for 1000 
[10, 20]
```

Comment: Thanks! I kind of ended up with something very similar to this with 2 for loops. My follow up question would be - what if I have a value in countList that doesn't appear in any ranges? Is there a good way to handle that?

Comment: Nothing will show up for that value. So, no special handling needed.

Comment: Would there be a way to handle that though?

Comment: What are you expecting? Maybe I can think of something on those lines then.

Comment: Sure, so ultimately I would like to pair the countList value [150,250] with the associated finalValue [10,20]. In this case every countList value is "True" within one of the ranges - but what if the there is a countList value of "1000" that doesn't fall within either range value? Maybe I could add another another item in the lotSize list with an extreme range and maybe a special finalValue value - and then check to see if the special finalValue is ever assigned and throw an error?

Comment: If the countList value doesn't match any of the ranges, you can print it out. Updated the code.

Comment: ah, this makes sense - I had messed up by having the else statement inside the for loop. This is much better, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that maps one entry in `countList` to a final value, then use `map()` and `list()` to repeat this for every element in `countList`:

```py
def get_final_value(item, lotSize):
    for entry in lotSize:
        if item in entry['range']:
            return entry['finalValue']
    
    raise ValueError(f"{item} is in not any of the ranges")

countList = [150,250]
lotSize = [{'range': range(100,200), 'finalValue': 10},{'range': range(201,300), 'finalValue': 20},{'range': range(301,400), 'finalValue': 30}]

result = list(map(lambda x: get_final_value(x, lotSize), countList))
print(result) # Prints [10, 20]
```

Comment: Thanks! lambda/map/list are mostly new to me, so I will have to break this one down to ensure I fully understand the functionality. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: I attempted to earlier, but it seems I am still too new - it requires a reputation level of 15.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach that came to my mind is what follows:

```py
[y["finalValue"] for y in lotSize for x in countList if x in y["range"]]
```

##### Output

```
[10, 20]
```

But note that, this will results in duplicates if you both `countSize` values exist in the `range` key. In this case, you just need to transform it to set and then transform it to list in order to remove the duplicates.